# How can I see the name of the record in a form view?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I am using odoo v8 and I have added a module "`Base candidat`".
The problem that I have is when I click on a record on  "`Base Candidat`"  I have in the form view `hr_basecandidat,1`(1 is for the `id`) I don't have the name of the candidate .
This picture will clearify my problem.

[Problem in the form view (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnSjE.png)
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two way:

1. use `_rec_name='any_field_name'`
2. create a field **display_name** and  set it's value

Comment: for the 1 way should I add this _rec_name='any_field_name' in base_candidat.py or in the xml view ?? the same issue if i want to use the second way . thank u in advance

Comment: Thank u so much Prakash I used the first way .

Comment: in the base_candidat.py

Comment: yes that's what I did and it worked Thk u so much again .

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow KhadijaAB if @PrakashSharma answer works for you. please consider accepting it as the correct answer as a way of saying thank you and gracefully removing the question from 'un-answered' odoo questions.